# Dynamic Month filter at form start

Tags: ms-access, vba

I got a filter for [my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKQUt.png), where I can choose a month - all datas, related to that month will then be shown. **Translation:** *Datenauswahl = Choose month*

My Problem is, 90% of the time, the user wants to work at the current month and dont want to see past datas. 
Everytime the user is switching a tab at the navigation form, the filter resets.

So  tried Default value of my combobox: `Format(Datum();"mm")` 
**Result:** [Current month input: Yes | Filter: No](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpVEx.png). So there have to be a possibillity, that after the default value has been loaded, the form checks the value of the combobox and filter it, everytime when swichting navigation tabs or On Load.

At my form, I activated *Filter at Load*.
The Filter of the Form itself is:        `Format([tbl_taetigkeitserfassung.TaetigkeitsDatum], 'mm') = '11'` -> bc of the combobox. A Value like:          `Format([tbl_taetigkeitserfassung.TaetigkeitsDatum], 'mm') = Format(Datum();'mm')` Is not working

I would appreciate some help or ideas to improve my user experience

BTW: code of the combobox, if needed:

```
Private Sub Kombinationsfeld479_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Kombinationsfeld479 = "Alle" Then
        Me.FilterOn = False
    ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.Kombinationsfeld479) Then
        Me.Filter = "Format([tbl_taetigkeitserfassung.TaetigkeitsDatum], 'mm')='" & Me.Kombinationsfeld479 & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Hard to understand, whats the problem, but what I can see is that you mix `;` and `,` in one expression: `Format([tbl_taetigkeitserfassung.TaetigkeitsDatum], 'mm') = Format(Datum();'mm')`. Usually `;` is used in object properties and `,` in VBA. Maybe thats the cause why your filter isn't accepted?

Comment: added some pics for explanation.   the `;` and `,` arent the problems. Fetfingered when I was wroting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some test I can say, that the following combination of form properties works fine here. The form automatically applies the filter when opening.

- `Filter On Load`: `Yes`
- `Filter`: `Format([TaetigkeitsDatum],"mm")=Format(Date(),"mm")`

So it looks like `tbl_taetigkeitserfassung.` is wrong in this case and should be removed. Also take care to replace the `;` by a `,` like in my example.

Comment: This will stop working properly the moment the database accumulates more than a year's worth of data.

Comment: @SunKnight: Regarding the current year only, this was not part of the question, but it's safe to assume that's what he wants. Belonging the `Month` function I agree completely, that's a slightly better approach.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to check with the OP or at least alert them to the potential issue. It could be the case (which is why I did not downvote I just commented), or it may just be something that hadn't occurred to them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all will your database never have more than one year's worth of data? Your current filtering process will stop working once you have data from more than one year. Use "yyyy-mm" date format to account for that.

For your filtering to work as you want you must follow every change in the filter (or even enabling it or disabling it) with Me.Requery so that the form updates based on the new filter.

Comment: Sry for late reply but i am on the road. My database will have several years(hopefully). The only reason Why I formatted it into MM is, that i will archive all datas at 31.12 of each year. Thanks for ur replies. I Will Check ur answers tomarrow evening or at monday., and will then upvote ofc.